# Squares as sum of squares

Tags: nt.number-theory, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, tiling

For which positive integers *n* is $n^2$ the sum of precisely *n* smaller positive squares?
Of these *n* x *n* squares, which can be actually cut into *n* smaller squares?

Comment: Is $0$ allowed?

Comment: 0  is not allowed

Comment: The first problem is surely very easy by the four square theorem.

Comment: For even numbers larger than 2, one can make one of the geometric squares have side n-2.  Gerhard "Still Working On Odd Case" Paseman, 2018.03.03.

Comment: Likewise, as Freddy Barrera points out, if n itself is a square then there is a trivial geometric solution: n squares of side n.

Comment: If $n$ odd is large enough, I'm guessing one can use a square of side $n-3$, together with an appropriate number of squares of sides $1$, $2$, and $3$. E.g., $n=99$, take 59 of side 3, 5 of side 2, and 34 of side 1.